# I'm trying to symmetrize an armature but its working weirdly

Tags: rigging, armature

[image]

[image]

(Ignore the weird bones connected to the head) I'm following this https://youtu.be/XkiWBSSuxLw tutorial and I need to symmetrize the armature but it's symmetrizing on the same side the armatures are already on. I have the .L thing done and I've tried rotating my armature but it won't work.

Comment: Hello, you probably need to apply the Rotation of your armature in Object mode in order to have the X symmetry work correctly

Comment: I've been trying rotating it in object mode and edit mode and it always ends up on the same side as already existing bones

Comment: don't rotate it in Object mode, just apply the rotation (Ctrl A), or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/